RStudio Server (Open Source Version) Custom Auth
I'm trying to setup RStudio Server (open source version) with custom authentication. I currently have NGINX/OpenResty performing the proxy OICD authentication/authorization, but haven't figured out a way to pass the user information to RStudio. All the documentation I found relates to the Pro version, which unfortunately isn't an option. I could theoretically turn off authentication all together, but since multiple users will be using it I need some way for a directory to be created/loaded for users when they access the application.
Has anyone had any luck integrating open source RStudio Server with OICD or any kind of custom authentication? Even if it doesn't match exactly what I'm trying to, hopefully it'll give me some insight how make modifications.
